# What are the most common algorithms in the field of computational geometry?

Tags: computer-science

So far I've touched on various aspects of computational geometry including constructive planar geometry (locus intersections), algorithms for planar graph topologies, 3D DDA, and most recently a 2D convex hull implementation using Graham's Scan and k-means clustering represented as Voronoi diagrams.

It's a fascinating field. I'm interested to know more. I would like to know which algorithms are most common in this field, and what they do.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as it requires extended discussion and there is no clear correct answer. More specific question would be better, for example, "What algorithm do I need to do X?" or "What algorithm allows me to do Y?".

Comment: Thanks, I'm well aware of the rules of stack exchange. However I am asking what is in widespread use, which I think is a solid enough basis for a question.

Comment: Rephrased just a few bits; I think the question can stay open in this form. It is answerable, and there are other questions much more vague than this one.

Comment: @Rook - it's still asking for a list of algorithms rather than for ones to solve a specific problem.

Comment: @ChrisF - I'm reading this question as "What are common algorithms specific to computational geometry field?". Don't see where that is offtopic in the FAQ or that list of six.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to create a list of most used in the field, I know only the ones I used :) But a good place to look for is in the O'Rourke book [Computational Geometry in C](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html). It was the book my University adviser asked to go through as a way to get acquainted in the field.

The same author, O'Rourke, has a computational geometry handbook if I recall correctly.

Comment: Since you were the only one who answered this question before it got closed, guess you are the winner!